# loopback create a response field for results

Tags: loopbackjs

So I got this application where a user has many orders and orders have many payments and I would like to respond (when querying for users) with some additional fields for each user which should not be retrieved from the database but computed:

- orders_count: the number of orders each user has
- payments_count: the number of payments each user has (calculated from orders)
- has_active_order: if it has an active order (a recent payment for that order)

  etc...

It should be possible because it's quite an overkill to display a list of 100 users and multiply that with another 300 requests to retrieve this data from the server....I just can't find any docs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your question, but if you're looking for an approach to reduce the number of requests I can think of 2 options:

1. Add 3 additional columns in the User table. Sure it creates
   redundancy, but sometimes this is necessary in order to improve
   performance. An easy way to keep these values up to date would be to
   use triggers at the database level.
2. Retrieve your data using a stored procedure / a more complex query.
   You can add extra columns in your result set.

Comment: thank you for taking the time but 1. defeats the whole purpose of using a relational database (which I'm using for this app) and 2. doesn't really work with loopback which generates a REST api based on model definition (json). I'm aware of such options but I was interested to find out if loopback itself supports such things.